# amp-iframe issues & limitations

Tags: iframe, amp-html, amp-iframe

So I've been trying to implement amp-iframe in my code after thoroughly reading its documentation and multiple articles on the matter. The issue is that I can't seem to satisfy the rules.

The most common error I get is **Origin of  must not be equal to container** since I can't serve the iframe from the same domain as the amp page.

When removing the **allow-same-origin** from the sandbox attribute, I get **DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.**

Also tried using TinyURL to redirect my domain with a short Url version, but I'm still getting the same error as before.

Finally, when I removed the sandbox attribute, I'd get **Blocked script execution in '' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set**

```
<amp-iframe layout="responsive" src={`${videoPageUrl}`} sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin" width="16" height="9" scrolling="no" resizable="" allowfullscreen="true">
  <amp-img layout="fill" alt="Image without a caption" class="w-100 mw-100 h-auto" width="600" height="450" placeholder="true" src={thumbnailImage}>
    </amp-img>
  <div overflow="" tabIndex="0" role="button" aria-label="Watch more">Watch more!</div>
</amp-iframe>
</>
```

Comment: Give me a link to the video(what you write in the src attribute), I'll try to help you.